# Set div on get method fail in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a div's text to "not found" in case the script fails to get the url in the script. I am using jQuery 1.4 version and I have to continue with it for some reason. Can anyone suggest some good ideas?

#### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slides").html("");
    $.get('someURl',

    function (d) {
        var i = 0;
        var array = [];
        var anchorImg = '';
        $(d).find('entry').each(function () {
            anchorImg = "<img id='imageID" + i + "' width='480' height='380'/>"
            $("#slides").append(anchorImg);
            var $entry = $(this);
            var pic = $entry.find('content').attr('src');
            array[i] = pic;
            var ankita = "imageID" + i;
            document.getElementById(ankita).src = array[i];
            i++;
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: switch your $.get to $.ajax (it's just a pass-through) so you can provide a fail handler.

Comment: version 1.4 release date: January 14, 2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.4 does not have deferred functions so your only option is to convert the `$.get` to a `$.ajax` call and use the `error` handler:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'someURl', 
    success: function(d) {
        var i = 0;
        var array = [];
        var anchorImg = '';

        $(d).find('entry').each(function() {
            anchorImg= "<img id='imageID" + i + "' width='480' height='380'/>"
            $("#slides").append(anchorImg);
            var $entry = $(this);
            var pic = $entry.find('content').attr('src');
            array[i] = pic;
            var ankita = "imageID" + i;
            document.getElementById(ankita).src = array[i];
            i++;
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#slides').text('Not found');
    }
});
```

You really should be pushing to use the latest version of jQuery though. 1.4 is nearly 4 years out of date!

Comment: is it not possible to do it by declaring a variable and incrementing its value in get method of jQuery and then checking if it has increased?

Comment: Possibly - but that would be a very hacky way of doing it. The code in my example if using the browsers internal XHR response to determine if there was an error.